# javascript .on() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select list, `#select1` and when the user chooses an option from this list, a certain action happens. I tried to do it with the following javascript code but sadly it is not working:

SCRIPT

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on( "change", "#select1", function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

So when I choose a certain option, I don't get the test alert.

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**

HTML

```
<select id="select1">
      <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose your country</option>
      <option value="2">Canada</option>
      <option value="3">France</option>
      <option value="4">India</option>
      <option value="5">Poland</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Check your console (press `F12`) on your browser, check for any errors.

Comment: What JQuery version are you using @zahi

Comment: Your syntax seems correct. It must be the selector? What is the HTML of the select box?

Comment: @Tomalak that's bad advice - for accesibility purposes `change` should always be used on `select` elements so that events are still raised when they are used with a keyboard. Also, there is nothing in the OPs code which should not work. The error must lie elsewhere.

Comment: I'm on jquery-1.10.2.min.js, and working on wordpress if this is of of any relevance. I edited the code to show the html

Comment: @Tomalak I just tried it here in Chrome 33 on OSX, it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/4YdeV/ The event is not raised when changing the selected option with the keyboard. I haven't tried it in other browsers as I'm on my macbook, but I don't think what you are stating is the case.

Comment: no errors in the console!

Comment: Mhh, you're right. I'll delete my comment, it's bad advice indeed.

Comment: @zahidaoui So you might try to make your not working code into a jsfiddle. Or you show an URL to the real code.

Answer (score 2):

I think This will Work

```
$('body').on('change','#select1',function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/KY8BF/3/)**

Comment: still no result. I'm gonna kill myself! i've been struggeling with it for 2 hours now!